# Simple regex extract folders

Tags: java, regex

What would be the most efficient way to cover all cases for a retrieve of `folder1/folder22`

from:

```
http://localhost:8080/folder1/folder22/file.jpg
or
http://domain.com/folder1/folder22/file.jpg
or
http://127.0.0.0.1:8080/folder1/folder22/file.jpg
```

so there may be one or more folders/sub-folders. Basically I would like to strip the domain name and port if available and the file name at the end.

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class and `getPath()`?

Maybe it's not the most efficient way, but one of the simplest I think:

```
String[] urls = { 
  "http://localhost:8080/folder1/folder22/file.jpg", 
  "http://domain.com/folder1/folder22/file.jpg",
  "http://127.0.0.0.1:8080/folder1/folder22/file.jpg" };
for (String url : urls)
  System.out.println(new File(new URL(url).getPath()).getParent());
```

Comment: I would prefer this over a regex solution because a) it's easier to understand because it's more explicit, b) it's the right tool for the job, and c) it probably handles edge cases a lot nicer than a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use Java's URL parser for this, but if it *has* to be a regex:

```
\b(?=/).*(?=/[^/\r\n]*)
```

will match `/folder1/folder22` in all your examples.

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\b(?=/).*(?=/[^/\r\n]*)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
    }
```

**Explanation:**

`\b`: Assert position at a word boundary (this will work before a single slash, but not between slashes or after a `:`)

`(?=/)`: Assert that the next character is a slash.

`.*`: Match anything until...

`(?=/[^/\r\n]*)`: ...exactly one last `/` (and anything else except slashes or newlines) follows.

Comment: Thanx Tim Pietzcker, just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.+/([^/]+/[^/]+)/[^/]+$
```

Comment: This only works for exactly two folders, but any number (>=1) is possible according to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the last two directories from a url is the following:

```
preg_match("/\/([^\/]+\/){2}[^\/]+$/", $path, $matches);
```

If matched, And $matches[1] will always contain what you want, no matter filename of full url.